# create a function to integrate in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I tried to follow the exact example here on my dataset but I get an error `Error in match.fun(f) : 'df1$chla' is not a function, character or symbol`

Example used: https://rdrr.io/github/jiho/castr/man/integrate.html

I created a dummy dataset below and it comes up with the same error.

what does the error mean? I want to integrate over a certain depth for multiple variables. for example, with the example below, I would like to integrate floro and chla over the top 50m.

```
 (df1 <- data.frame(depth = c(1:201, by = 2),
              floro = c(1:201, by = 2),
              chla = c(1:100, by = 1)))

 (df2 <- integrate(df1$chla, df1$depth, from=0, to=50, method="constant"))
```

Comment: Did you load `library(castr)` first? I get the same error when I don't, as there is a function in base R, `stats::integrate`, which expects a function in the first term.

Comment: There is a base R function `integrate()` but it looks like the example your reference, uses the `library(jiho/castr)` that might also have the `integrate()` function defined.  I believe you are using the Base R function and not the version in the jiho/castr package.